# SDL image gives undefined reference for libpng in executable

Tags: codeblocks, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 image to load png files and it works quite fine within the IDE (Codeblocks & MinGW under windows). But as soon as I build it and run it from the executable it gives me an undefined reference for "inflate validate" within libpng16-16.dll

I browsed the web and found out it could be about static linking as well as linking zlib before sdl image.

So I tried it with static linking and checked if zlib is linked after sdl image, which it is. Still the error occurs.

Any ideas what could be the reason? I also copied the regarding dlls in the executable direction, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, zlib.dl must be included in the directory of the executable file itself.